Test Class for MessagingSession trigger (enhanced channel)
I have a trouble to try to create a test class for my trigger.
My trigger is executed when the agent change the active to inactive. This event is dispatched by a button into the enhanced conversation component. The trigger detects the change and mark a checkbox in true (Inactive__c).
When I created my test class, receive an error that the status field is not writeable :
    @isTest(seeAllData = true)
public static void validateChange(){
    Final List<MessagingEndUser> userTst = MX_Test_Data_Factory.createMessagingEndUser(1,true);
    Final List<MessagingSession> messaging = MX_Test_Data_Factory.createMessagingSession(1, userTst[0].Id, true);
    Test.startTest();
    List<MessagingSession> getSession = [SELECT Id, Status FROM MessagingSession WHERE Id =:messaging[0].Id LIMIT 1];
    getSession[0].Status = 'Inactive';
    List<MessagingSession> getSessionChanged = [SELECT Id, Status, Inactive__c FROM MessagingSession WHERE Id =:messaging[0].Id LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals(getSessionChanged[0].Inactive__c == true, true, 'Trigger is not working');
    update getSession;
    Test.stopTest();
    
}

I would like to know, how can I solve my issue ?
Thanks.

I find a solution and I hope to help someone with my answer.
I have to made the update as a JSON answer(String) with a serialize.
Execute the update and in this moment the trigger starts to running.
I think that this solution is for the mutliple not writeable fields.
UPDATE: Someone put the explanation in other question.
    @isTest(seeAllData = true)
public static void validateChange(){
    Final List<MessagingEndUser> userTst = MX_Test_Data_Factory.createMessagingEndUser(1,true);
    Final List<MessagingSession> messaging = MX_Test_Data_Factory.createMessagingSession(1, userTst[0].Id, true);
    Test.startTest();
    List<MessagingSession> getSession = [SELECT Id, Status FROM MessagingSession WHERE Id =:messaging[0].Id LIMIT 1];
    //getSession[0].Status = 'Inactive';
    String jsonSession = '{' +
    '"Id": "'+getSession[0].Id +'",' +
    '"Status": "Inactive",' +
    '"EndedBy": "System"' +
    '}';
    System.debug('jsonSession: ' + jsonSession);
    MessagingSession jsonMesssaging = (MessagingSession) JSON.deserialize(jsonSession, MessagingSession.class);
    System.debug('jsonMesssaging: ' + jsonMesssaging);
    update jsonMesssaging;
    List<MessagingSession> getSessionChanged = [SELECT Id, Status, Inactive__c FROM MessagingSession WHERE Id =:messaging[0].Id LIMIT 1];
    Test.stopTest();

}

